# reset the actionButton value to 0 in r

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server

I have an R shiny app where in I select few parameters and I click on the action button. Initially for the first time I press the action button the value which will be 0 will set to 1 and will act accordingly. But once the action button is pressed and the action has taken place I wanna make this button usable for other values set after the initial setup, but I am not finding a way to setback the value of action button to 0 once it is turned to 1.

Please advice me to achieve this.

Thanks,
Santhosh

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Action buttons are not meant to retrieve a value, but to do something when clicked.

Comment: I agree nicola that action buttons are meant for doing something on a click but once the action is done I am trying to select other set of options and click on the same button so that the functionality is again taken care on a click but for new set of values.  If it can be done by any other option other that actionButton please advice me on that.

Comment: Maybe you can use two buttons, one of them to reset all the options. In any case, be more specific describing in detail the actions you want to perform after each click.

Answer (score 0):

I modified such that I am disabling the buttons once after user click the button by using updateaction function.

Thanks,
santhosh